# Copy one Redux Form Value to Another

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    let returnObject = {};
    if (state && state.form) {
        if (
            state.form.someFormName &&
            state.form.someFormName.values &&
            state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameX &&
            state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameX === "1"
        ) {
            state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameB =
                state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameA;

            state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameC =
                state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameD;

            state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameF =
                state.form.someFormName.values.fieldNameE;
        }
    }
    return returnObject;
}
```

This is Working Fine on selecting form field i am just copying redux form value to another field,How to do in Efficient Way?This is the Correct way to copy one form field into another ?

Comment: Why do you want to copy? Should they be in sync always? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: There are 2 section Left and right in the form,if  radio button is selected,then left section particular field will get that value which is selected in right section field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the Preferred method to change the state like this (You are mutating the state) Redux 2 Principle,Use this instead:
If you are using radio/checkbox, then onPress of that radio/checkbox you can copy all the field,then dispatch onChange action.
For Eg:

```
<Field
        type="radio"
        name="fieldNameX"
        value="1"
        onRadioPress={this.someMethod}
        component={CustomRadioButton}
    />

someMethod() {
        let formValues = Object.assign({}, this.props.formValues);
        this.props.dispatch(
            change("SomeForm", "fieldWantToCopy", value)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `formValueSelector` to connect to your form value and than dispatch `change` action creator to update any field with your value.

Here is the example with textboxes(you can update it to use datePicker):

```
import {change, formValueSelector} from 'redux-form';

let FormName = (props) => {
    const {dispatch, handleSubmit, firstValue} = props;
    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <label>First Value</label>
            <Field
                name='firstValue'
                component='input'
                type='text'
                placeholder='First Value'
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Copy value</label>
            <div>
                <Field
                    name='checkbox'
                    component='input'
                    type='checkbox'
                    value='checkboxValue'
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        if (e.target.checked) {
                            dispatch(change('formName', 'secondValue', firstValue));
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Second Value</label>
            <Field name='secondValue' component='input' type='text'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
};

const selector = formValueSelector('formName');

connect(
    state => ({
        firstValue: selector(state, 'firstValue'),
    })
)(FormName);
```

Comment: and then?how do i set/initialize that value to my field?

Comment: i updated the answer with using of `change` action creator

Comment: I have only one form not 2,and i am using picker not textbox.What's the difference between in your approach and on mine?

Comment: your approach contradicts the second Redux principle: 'State is read-only' (The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object describing what happened.)

Comment: Thanks it is working ,but here is one problem,Picker not consistently fire onValueChange.                                                                                  <Field name="some_name" options={options} component={CustomPicker}/> ,Fired on alternate clicks,it is due to redux Field that i am using

Comment: can you show the code of your CustomPicker? i believe that it must have onChange action

Comment: <Picker
     mode={mode ? mode : "dropdown"}
     style={style}
     selectedValue={input.value}
     enabled={enabled}
     onValueChange={value => {
      input.onChange(value);
      if (onValueChange) onValueChange(value);
     }}>
     {options &&
      options.map((eachOption, index) => (
       <Item key={index} label={eachOption.name} value={eachOption.id} />
      ))}
    </Picker>                                                              this is the custom picker,we can use setState here but then we can't use Redux Field Value

Comment: Igor Alemsaow,any solution please help

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/ry-Dx9jYM pasted the code,not working in this as i have to configure/install all dependencies related react-redux